# Jupyter notebook crashes after rendering pybullet-gym environment

Tags: jupyter-notebook, reinforcement-learning, pybullet

I am using `pybullet-gym` to evaluate my policy model and visualize its interactions; however, when it renders the environment using the following sample code (taken from [its own repo](https://github.com/benelot/pybullet-gym)) jupyter notebook crashes and restarts its kernel  :

```
import gym
import pybulletgym

env = gym.make('HumanoidPyBulletEnv-v0')
env.render()
env.reset()
```

Here is the message in shell:

```
startThreads creating 1 threads.
starting thread 0
started thread 0 
argc=2
argv[0] = --unused
argv[1] = --start_demo_name=Physics Server
ExampleBrowserThreadFunc started
X11 functions dynamically loaded using dlopen/dlsym OK!
X11 functions dynamically loaded using dlopen/dlsym OK!
Creating context
Created GL 3.3 context
Direct GLX rendering context obtained
Making context current
GL_VENDOR=NVIDIA Corporation
GL_RENDERER=GeForce MX150/PCIe/SSE2
GL_VERSION=3.3.0 NVIDIA 450.102.04
GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION=3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
pthread_getconcurrency()=0
Version = 3.3.0 NVIDIA 450.102.04
Vendor = NVIDIA Corporation
Renderer = GeForce MX150/PCIe/SSE2
b3Printf: Selected demo: Physics Server
startThreads creating 1 threads.
starting thread 0
started thread 0 
MotionThreadFunc thread started
ven = NVIDIA Corporation
ven = NVIDIA Corporation

XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1"
      after 21540 requests (21540 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```